# UIView, its superview and touchesBegan:

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiview, touch, uiresponder

Suppose I have a UIViewController subclass that takes care of some UIViews. These UIViews are added as subviews of the UIViewController's `view` property):

UIViewController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    UIImageView *smallImageView...
    [self.view addSubview:smallImageView];

    UIButton *button..
    [self.view addSubview:button];

    UIView *bigUIView.. // covers the entire screen (frame = (0.0, 0.0, 1024.0, 768.0))
    [self.view addSubview:bigUIView];
...
}
```

AFAIK, since the `bigUIView` is the frontmost view and covers the entire screen, it will receive the `touchesBegan:withEvent:` and the other views, such as `button` won't receive any touch event.

In my application `bigUIView` must be the topmost view because it holds the main user interface objects (CALayers, actually, the main game objects) that, when animated, must be on top of all other secondary UI elements (UIButtons, etc). However, I'd like to be able to still have the UIButtons and other objects in the Responder Chain.

I tried implementing the following in the `bigUIView` class:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {    
    [self.superview touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];

    ... hit test the touch for this specific uiview..
}
```

Notes:

1. `bigUIView`'s superview refers to the UIViewController's `view` property, does it propagate the touch event to all of it's subviews?
2. `bigUIView` must have `userInteractionEnabled = YES` because it also handles user input.
3. I can't bring the `button`/`smallImageView` to front because it would appear above the main game objects (sublayers of `bigUIView`).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try overriding `pointInside:withEvent:` in the `bigUIView` class to return `NO` if the point is inside the frame rectangle of one of the other subviews of the background view. Since it's a sibling of these other views, the hit testing mechanism will continue testing the other subviews and find the one corresponding to the point the user touched.

Alos, consider implementing the event phase methods (`-touchesBegan:withEvent:`, etc.) in your `UIViewController` subclass rather than in the `bigUIView` class. iOS inserts view controllers behind their views in the responder chain, so event messages will bubble up to the view controller unless one of the other subviews (for example, a button) intercepts it. The view controller can then send whatever messages you like to any of its views.

Comment: Thanks jlehr, `pointInside:withEvent:` is the solution. By returning NO when the point is inside the frame rectangle of one of the other subviews cause the `bigUIView`'s `-touchesBegan:withEvent:` method not to be called and the `button`'s action being triggered. Note that this cause a coupling between the `bigUIView` and the `button`. How can I intercept the event phase methods only in the `UIViewController` when the `bigUIView` cover the whole screen? Creating a different method signature in `bigUIView` class and have it delegated by the "catch all" `UIViewController` class?

Comment: No, don't implement the event phase methods in `bigUIView` at all. That way the messages will get forwarded up the responder chain until they reach an object that has an overridden implementation (for example `UIButton` or your custom `UIViewController` subclass).

Comment: With respect to coupling, consider implementing a delegate method in your view controller that the `bigUIView` instance can call to make the actual decision. That way the view controller would be responsible for calculating which view gets the message and there'd be no coupling at all.

Comment: Ok, but what if my `bigUIView` needs the `-touchesBegan:withEvent:` delegate method arguments to work properly? Overriding will cause the Responder Chain to be stopped, do you suggest creating another event phase 'sibling' methods signatures and implement them in the `bigUIView` (such methods would be called by the `UIViewController`)?

Comment: One option is to route all touch event messages through the controller, and then let the controller decide what happens in response (in part by sending messages to one or more views). Another option would be to include a call to `[super touchesBegan:withEvent:]` at the end of each of the overridden methods in `bigUIView`, which would allow the messages to continue up the responder chain so that they'd be received by both the `bigUIView` and its controller.

Answer (score 0):

Normally in the responder chain, events are passes to superviews, not to subviews. Anyway, I would convert points in events to the button's local coordinate system, and if it hits, send an action to the controller.

Comment: I appreciate the commentary, It's an interesting solution. However I'm trying to avoid this high coupling between the `bigUIView` (which belongs to the "game package" (CALayers)) and other UI elements (created in the IB). Thanks

Comment: No problem. bigUIView still need not work with other UI elemets. But I agree jlehr's solution seems the way to go!